# How does Linux (Specifically, GNOME Fedora) calculate my position?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, fedora, gnome

I am using Fedora in GNOME with the positioning service, so the system can get the local time automatically.

However, when I connect to a VPN for a long time, it seems that the system think that my location is at the location the VPN server is located.

The question is how does the system calculate my location (like the network protocol running or the server's IP address requesting). I would like to block the service temporarily (with a firewall or something) when connected to the VPN instead of closing the positioning service in GNOME manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location is estimated based on the public IP address, which can be (to some extent and accuracy) mapped to the location. When you are using VPN for all the traffic, also these checks go through the VPN and your public IP is the IP of the server. You can verify/test it with

```
https://www.whatismyip.com/
```

It will show your IP and estimated location.

Comment: Is there a known service provider of this service in Fedora or known configuration file?

Comment: IMHO, [GeoClue](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/GeoClue/) is used in GNOME to resolve the location for the applications.

Comment: Yes, it uses Geoclue. And Geoclue uses a [variety of sources](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Maps/Geolocation), including [Mozilla Location Service](https://location.services.mozilla.com/). This prefers using nearby wifi access points for location, but falls back to IP. Or it can get information from the GPS of an attached 3G modem.

Comment: @mattdm thanks for clarification. Generally and probably in case of the OP based on the description, the IP location is used.

Comment: It seems that GNOME is actually using GeoClue. Its service name is geoclue.service and can be disabled manually (to solve my problem).